# How Impala does not use map reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, impala

I am going through this [link.](https://www.quora.com/How-does-an-MPP-engine-on-YARN-compare-to-MapReduce-on-YARN-as-a-distributed-computing-paradigm-see-details)

Generally Impala is compared to Hadoop Map-Reduce/Hive but here I want it to compare it from the map reduce programming paradigm.

I am having hard time understanding how Impala(or MPP) does not use map reduce paradigm as it should also break query into smaller tasks and then aggregate the result. It should not matter if it is done in memory or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider reading Google's Dremel papers.  Impala is based on it.

Comment: Impala does break apart tasks and performs aggregates... Plenty of tools did that before the MapReduce term existed. BTW, Tez or Spark on Hive also do not "use MapReduce"